# Difference between these two pointer to char initialisations

Tags: c

I know this has been answer before, but I can't find the question.
What are the differences between these two initialisations:

```
int main() 
{
    char* pch1;
    char* pch2;

    pch1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
    strcpy(pch1, "Text");

    pch2 = "Text";
}
```

Comment: One points to heap memory, the other to the static data segment of the prgoram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: don't cast the return value from `malloc` - it's a common source of errors. [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

```
pch1 = malloc(sizeof(char) * 5);
```

assigns a pointer to a dynamically allocated block of 5 bytes on the heap.

```
pch2 = "Text";
```

should ideally be avoided because it assigns a pointer to a string literal. String literals are read-only on most OSes and is also a common source of mistakes. If you do this you should make the pointer to `const`

```
const char * pch2 = "Text";
```

Comment: I haven't programmed that much in C, but everywhere I see that the return value from malloc it is cast. Can you tell me why this is wrong?

Comment: In C++ you have to cast, in C you should not. Explained in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 2):

There are three main differences here:

- The first one copies the content of a string literal into dynamic memory, while the second one points to that literal directly.
- Modifying `pch1` string is legal; modifying `pch2` string is illegal
- You need to free `pch1` to avoid memory leak.

For completeness, consider `pch3` which is initialized like this:

```
char tmp[] = "Text";
char *pch3 = tmp;
```

This `pch3` is modifiable like your `pch1`, but it does not need freeing, because the content of the string is copied into automatic memory.

Comment: Hmm, so thats it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`pch1` points to heap

**you can modify it within bounderies**

plus you **have to free it**

other points to static data segment
**you can not modify it**

Answer (score 0):

1. pch1 will use heap memory for storing your data
2. pch2 - using stack memory